# IndexError while extracting data from files

Tags: python

I have a hundred files each with three columns. 
In a python script, I extract the three columns for each file :

```
for i in range(1,100)
  # extract data 
  os.chdir('directory/to/files')
  fileName = 'file'+str(i).dat
  f = open(fileName)
  c1 = [l.split()[0] for l in f]
  f.close()
  f = open(fileName)
  c2 = [l.split()[1] for l in f]
  f.close()
  f = open(fileName)
  c3 = [l.split()[2] for l in f]
  f.close()
  doAnalysis()
```

Surprisingly, I have an `IndexError` at iteration 15 pointing at line 12 of the above code saying : `list index out of range`.
I thought python is thinking that my file15.dat has less then 3 columns, so I added this just before line 12 :

```
if i==15:
 c3IF = []
 for l in f:
   print(len(l.split())
   c3IF.append(l.split()[2])
```

The `c3IF` list seems to contain the third column of file15.dat entirely and l.split is always of length 3. I don't understand why the comprehension list c3 fails at a specific iteration while the two other comprehension lists do not.

Comment: It does not fail when you do the normal for loop method? Does it even fail now?

Comment: Try adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right above the assignment of `c3`, and seeing what the value of `l` is at that point. On the first few loops, skip past it by typing `continue` (or, indeed, wrap it in an if-statement). That eliminates any ambiguities created by printing rather than inspecting the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found out that the error is raised at iteration 16 and not at iteration 15 and that in the long long file16.dat, I had a line where the third column data in missing, causing the IndexError.